# Why can't I trim a file using `head`?

Tags: io-redirection, head

Given a file, foo.txt:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Say we want to change it to contain:

```
1
2
3
```

Why does `head -n3 foo.txt > foo.txt` leave foo.txt empty?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This happens because the `>` redirection occurs before the `head` program is started. The `>` redirection truncates the file if it exist, so when the `head` is reading a file it is already empty.

Comment: Interesting. Do you have any detail on *why* it works this way?

Comment: well, first bash (or the shell you are using) opens/creates the files it will use for redirection. Then it replaces the currently used file descriptors for stdin, stdout and stderr with the file descriptors it created for redirection as necessary. Then it executes the `fork` and `exec` system calls to start a new process thus the started process has the standard files redirected. Then bash restores its original file descriptors for itself. This is roughly what happens.

Comment: `head`, `sed` etc. are generally *inline editors*

Comment: Instead of redirecting the output of `head` to the file, you could pipe it to `tee` as such: `head -n3 foo.txt | tee foo.txt`. `tee` won't write to the file until it receives the data from `head` via the pipe.

Comment: @EvanTeitelman, ? Is `tee` documented to only open the output file *after* it has received input?